# How to properly load javascript and styles from local Apache webserver in broswer?

Tags: javascript, android, apache, ip, styles

I am accessing Apache webserver intalled on Windows machine from Andorid device in local network. DOM elements loads in browser normally but javascript and styles not. Viewing page source shows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/shop/app.js'></script>
```

How can I tell Android to look for files in home dircetory (127.0.0.1) of target device not itselfs home directory?

Comment: What url are you using to access the DOM elements?

Comment: ip of apache installed machine is 192.168.3.1 . I am accessing the apache machine trhough android device connected to same network. Text and html elements loads fine but not javascript and styles. When viewing page source of webpage in andorid device. it shows http://127.0.0.1/wp-content/themes/shop/app.js for javascript. it is a home directoy of apache machine not Androids. This causes the problem.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site using http://192.168.3.1/wp-content/themes/shop/app.js ?

Comment: Thank you, it worked for homepage! it seems i have to force all links inside app to point to 192.168.3.1 so to be able to navigate inside app

Comment: Good news, I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed Wordpress "siteurl" from "localhost" to IP address of the machine where apache is running. After this I was able to browse from Android phone on the same network just by typing IP address.